# Dataadapter's Update method not working when programatically changing values in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataadapter

I have a **Users**(Id, Firstname, Lastname) table in database

My simple app : 
datagridview is bound to the Users table and when I change the content of a particular cell and call the Update method of my dataadapter

Update Button:

```
//update changes to database
peopleTableAdapter.Update(databindTestDataSet.People);
```

it works, it reflects the values back to my database.

[image]

Now what I want to do now is make my datagridview only

```
dgvUsers.ReadOnly = true;
```

and make the changes through a textbox that will *programatically* change the cell's value and then reflecting the changes back to the database by clicking the update button. **IT DOES NOT WORK** 
[image]

Update Button:

```
//get selected row
DataGridViewRow currentRow = dgvUsers.CurrentRow;
//set the cell's value from textbox
currentRow.Cells[1].Value = txtFirstname.Text;
currentRow.Cells[2].Value = txtLastname.Text;
//update changes to database
peopleTableAdapter.Update(databindTestDataSet.People);
```

how do i make this work?
my guess is that the cell needs to lose focus in order to make the changes

Comment: Update the `DataRow` not the `DataGridViewRow` and refresh the DGV. Deal with the data source to add/edit/remove items.

Comment: **Hint:** `dgvUsers.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem`